# how to find a td element with complex predicate using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML fragment from a table:

```
<td>
   <a href="xxa">
</td>
<td>
   <a href="xxy">
</td>
```

I want to select all the td's that contain an 'a' element that contains an href beginning with "xx".

I tried:

```
$('td[a[href^="xx"]]')
```

but I get:

```
Error: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

How can I select this array of tds ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var tdEls = $('a[href^="xx"]').closest('td');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c8T2P/).

Which will select the `<a>` elements whose `href` starts with 'xx' and then find the closest ancestor element that is a `<td>`, returning a jQuery object containing those `<td>` elements.

If you want an array, however:

```
var tdEls = $('a[href^="xx"]').closest('td').map(function(){
    return $(this);
}).get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c8T2P/1/).

Or:

```
var tdEls = $('a[href^="xx"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).closest('td');
}).get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c8T2P/3/).

The previous two code snippets will return an array of jQuery objects, each of which can be chained with jQuery methods.

If you'd prefer a simple array of DOM nodes, however:

```
var tdEls = $('a[href^="xx"]').closest('td').get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c8T2P/2/).

Incidentally, a [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/getting-array-of-ancestors-based-on-descendants) comparison of approaches (the last approach, in Chromium 31/Ubuntu 12.10, is the fastest approach).

References:

- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Comment: why not `var tdEls = $('a[href^="xx"]').closest('td').get()`

Comment: Because I assumed he wanted, for whatever reason, an array of jQuery objects (hence `return $(this)`), rather than an array of plain DOM nodes; however you raise a good point and I have added that to the answer, thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I'm going with your answer. - Bill

Answer (score 1):

I might go with .has() to do the filter

```
$('td').has('a[href^="xx"]')
```

It selects all `td` elements which has a anchor element with href starting with `xx`